# How to use map instead of for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `multiple images` that I want to upload but my question is I want to stop to upload more than 2MB file so how to check all selected files size not more than 2MB using map instead of for loop?

```
console.log(this.state.files); // see screenshot
```

*This is console:*

[image: This is console]

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.files.length; i++) {
  if(this.state.files[i].size > 2000000){
     console.log("files is ok");
  }else{
     console.log("files not allow to more then 2MB");
  }
}
```

Comment: let uploadFiles=this.state.files.filter(p=>p.size < 2000000);

Comment: You are looking for `Array.filter()` not `Array.map()`

Comment: @Weedoze To me, `Array.some()` makes even more sense, unless you want to tell the user which files are too fat, or just submit the lean ones without an error message.

Comment: @Amadan OP is asking to stop uploading file bigger than 2MB. Indeed it is not totally clear if he wants to stop all the uploads or still uploads every files under 2MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files  :

```js
this.state.files
```

Files of size less than 2000000

```js
let smallSizeFiles = this.state.files.filter((file) => file.size < 2000000 );
```

Files of size equal or greater than 2000000

```js
let largeSizeFiles = this.state.files.filter((file) => file.size => 2000000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//print the warnings as in OP post
this.state.files.forEach(file =>{
   if(file.size < 2000000){
     console.log("files is ok");
  }else{
     console.log("files not allow to more then 2MB");
  } 
})
//filter array and upload
this.state.files.filter(e=>e.size < 2000000).forEach(e=>{/*upload here*/})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var images = this.state.files.filter(file => file.size < 2000000)
```

Comment: why you need a { bracket with return statement arrow function will return the single line by default

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if every file is less than 2 MB, then use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
const areFilesValid = this.state.files.every(f => f.size < 2000000);

if (areFilesValid) {
  // continue uploading
} else {
  // don't upload
}
```

(You should compare the size with 2 * 1024 * 1024 and not 2000000)